# Counting more elements then it should be

Tags: python, opencv

I'm learning OpenCV with Python, and I want to learn how to count objects/elements in an image.

I wrote a code for counting, but I get wrong results. There are 12 elements in the image, and I get 40, but also some elements are not counted.

I do not know what am I doing wrong.

This is the code that I have:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('slika.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

print('There are 12 elements on this image')

#cv2.imshow('img', gray)
#cv2.waitKey(0)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)
contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,1)

print('Number of elements found:', len(contours))

for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the default image, with 12 elements:

[image]

This is the result:

[image]

You see that the pink and two yellow elements are not recognized, but it's the problem with green one.

What am I doing wrong, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several points, where to improve your current code.

1. If you actually have a look at your `gray` image, you see that your threshold of `127` is too low. The yellow and pink structures have grayvalues above `127`, and then are omitted by your `cv2.threshold`. For the same reason the green structure is fragmented. And, in general, better use the actual enum values like [`cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gaa9e58d2860d4afa658ef70a9b1115576) instead of their numerical values.
2. For the contour detection better use the [`cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71) retrieval mode, so you just consider most outer contours. Again, use enum values.

With these changes, your code works fine:

```py
import cv2

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('DIVmd.jpg')

# Convert image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Show grayscale image
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)

print('There are 12 elements on this image')

# Inverse binary threshold image with threshold at 224,
# i.e. every pixel with value above 224 is set to 0,
# and every pixel with value below 224 is set to 1
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 224, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Show thresholded image
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)

# Find contours
#   cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL:      retrieves only the extreme outer contours
#   cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE:  stores absolutely all the contour points
contours, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

print('Number of elements found:', len(contours))

# Iterate all found contours
for cnt in contours:

    # Draw contour in original/final image
    cv2.drawContours(img, [cnt], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Show final image
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For visualization purposes, this is your `gray` image:

[image: Gray]

This is the actual thresholded image `thresh`:

[image: Thresh]

And, finally the output `img`:

[image: Output]

Of course, the printed outputs are now also correct:

```
There are 12 elements on this image
Number of elements found: 12
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is dope my friend, you are the best !
Thanks!
Can you just please write a comments next to every line, because Im a noob :)
What does this do: `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL`, `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` etc

Comment: @taga I added some explanatory comments in the above code, please have look. Apart from that, please have a look at the OpenCV documentation on [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0), and additional links there.